Using dc.plot_network and cant print arrows
I am running this decoupler function which prints out a network using sources and targets of curated collection of TFs and their transcriptional targets. I have used Collectri as the collection (net), however I am not able to obtain the interactions between the sources and targets.
This is the tutorial I have followed: https://decoupler-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/dorothea.html
This is the function and parameters I am using:
#curated collection of TFs and their transcriptional targets 
net = dc.get_collectri(organism='human', split_complexes=False)

dc.plot_network(
    net=net,
    n_sources=['PAX5', 'EBF1', 'RFXAP'],
    n_targets=15,
    node_size=100,
    s_cmap='white',
    t_cmap='white',
    c_pos_w='darkgreen',
    c_neg_w='darkred',
    figsize=(5, 5)
)

And this is the output I get:


You might have already solved the issue, but I noticed that the node_size was too large, causing the nodes to be drawn outside the figure. Try setting a smaller node_size, like 0.5 or 1.

As It is currently written, your answer is more of a comment. You could improve your answer by including a working example using the link the OP provided that proves your assumption is correct. Doing so will help validate your answer and will likely increase the chances of upvotes. Thanks.
